# Adding repeat option to audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building audio player with jQuery. And I managed to do almost everything that I wanted, but I can not make song to repeat when I click on repeat button. It should repeat if I click on repeat button and if it is enabled, when I click again to disable it. 
I init audio with
 `music = new Audio()`
I tried to use some thing like:

```
$('.rep').on('click', function(){
    music.prop('loop');
})
```

but I can not get it work.

any advice, comment or tutorial would be helpful because I am looking to learn, not to copy/paste.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can add `eventListener` like this.. :

```
$('.rep').click(function(){
    myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
      this.currentTime = 0;
      this.play();
    }, false);
});
```

or just edit an attr loop like this [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrzEjQ) :

```
myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

$('.rep').click(function(){
    if(myAudio.loop != true){
      myAudio.loop = true;
      myAudio.play();
    } else {
      myAudio.loop = false;
      myAudio.currentTime = 0;
      myAudio.pause();
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It helps a little bit. The thing is that I want on one button, to enable/disable repetition.

Comment: I updated answer and CodePen.. just a simple if statement `if loop is true`

Comment: Thank you. It was really helpfull. I just change it a little bit to achieve what I need.

Comment: Nice, glad to hear that!